# Ansible playbook, create a user with the option --disabled-login

Tags: ansible, user-accounts

I need create a user with the option *--disabled-login* with ansible's playbook.

The command line is:

> sudo adduser --disabled-login git

I'm searching on [Ansible's](http://ansible.cc/docs/modules.html#user) documentation. And the option *system* is similar.

The playbook task is:

> user: name=git system=no

Is the option *system=no* the same as the option *--disabled-login*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, *system=no* is **not** the same as *--disabled-login*!
From the [adduser man-page](http://man.he.net/man8/adduser):

*--disabled-login

Do  not  run passwd to set the password.  The user won't be able              to use her account until the password is set.*

So when using Ansible's [user module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html), and you do not set a password, the login is disabled  anyway (unless SSH-keys are being setup in the account's $HOME).

Comment: Depending on your configuration, even if SSH keys are setup you may not be able to login in such an account. This is for example the default in Debian.